# Hash in Hash gives the wrong value in return?

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm trying to store a two dimensional Hash with the following keys:

- Dimension 1 = numerical but not consecutive
- Dimension 2 = strings (as :id and :value)

The problem happens when elements are not initialized.

```
memory = Hash.new(Hash.new(""))
memory[0][:value] = "station1"
memory[1][:value] # => "station1"
```

When I access `memory[1][:value]`, I get the value of `memory[0][:value]`. How is this possible? I though I would get an empty string.

Comment: Did my answer help you? Would be nice if you ask when somethings unclear or accept an answer otherwise :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what happens: with the first line you create a Hash object with the default value of a Hash object which has the default value of an empty string. When you access a non-existant key, the object will be returned:

```
irb(main):004:0> memory = Hash.new(Hash.new(""))
=> {}
irb(main):007:0> memory[0].object_id
=> 70350452886020
irb(main):008:0> memory[1].object_id
=> 70350452886020
irb(main):005:0> memory[0][:value]
=> ""
irb(main):006:0> memory[0][:value].object_id
=> 70137307419240
irb(main):007:0> memory[1][:value].object_id
=> 70137307419240
```

When you access the non-existant value of the inner hash, the default hash object will be returned. So by defining `memory[0][:value] = "station1"` with the key 0 not yet existing, you set the value `station1` for the key `:value` to the inner hash. When you now access another non-existant key on the outer hash, the inner hash will be returned again with the key `:value` already set to `"station1"`:

```
irb(main):008:0> memory[0][:value] = 'station1'
=> "station1"
irb(main):011:0> memory[0][:value]
=> "station1"
irb(main):012:0> memory[1][:value]
=> "station1"
irb(main):007:0> memory[0].object_id
=> 70350452886020
irb(main):008:0> memory[1].object_id
=> 70350452886020
irb(main):009:0> memory[0][:value].object_id
=> 70137307342120
irb(main):010:0> memory[1][:value].object_id
=> 70137307342120
```

So basically you change the inner hash by accessing non-existant keys on the outer hash, which returns a reference to the inner hash.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new hash object for each key. In your example, all keys share the same hash object.

```
memory = Hash.new{|h, k| h[k] = Hash.new("")}
memory[1][:value] # => ""
memory[1][:value] = "a"
memory[1][:value] # => "a"
memory[2][:value] # => ""
```